# Excel-VBA gradient colorstops

Tags: vba, excel

What is the best way to apply horizontal gradient fill effect to a cell through macro code?

I've set the desired gradient in Excel (right-click on cell B1, Format Cells..., Fill, Fill Effects, Two Colors, Horizontal, "Okay" all).

I then have the following code to find out how to represent this via code. When I step through the code, I can use the locals window to inspect the gradient and colorstops of the myrange object:

```
Dim myrange As range
Set myrange = ActiveSheet.range("B1")
```

Using this information, I can now hard-code the information in a macro, in hopes of duplicating the gradient fill by code:

```
'First, delete any previous gradient colorstops
For Each cs In myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
  cs.Delete
Next

'Then, assign the desired colorstops in the gradient
With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops
  .add color = 16777215
  Position = 0
  ThemeColor = 1
  TintAndShade = 0

  .add color = 7961087
  Position = 0.5
  ThemeColor = 0
  TintAndShade = 0

  .add color = 16777215
  Position = 1
  ThemeColor = 1
  TintAndShade = 0

End With
```

Unfortunately, this results in something that looks totally wrong. The most obvious thing that's wrong is that the gradient is in black and white, even as I adjust the RGB values.

Is there something else that should be added here?

Comment: have you tried using macro recorder just to see how it does it? For complex formatting and so on like this I often start there to see the properties needed then insert certain bits of it into my own 'clean' code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The assignment of ColorStops is not valid code. You need to add the colorstops and then set their properties. The macro recorder does it correctly.

```
Sub SetGradient()
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1")

    With myrange.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 90
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
    End With
    With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
        .Color = 16777215
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.5)
        .Color = 7961087
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With myrange.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
        .Color = 16777215
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Good advice, and it works perfectly. The good thing about this approach is that I can capture other fill effects and incorporate those into my code also. Thank you.